# bool query with filter does not return any documents

Tags: elasticsearch

The simple query

```
"query": {
    "simple_query_string": { "query":"great guide" } 
},
```

returns my document as expected, containing

```
"groups": [
        "Local Business"
],
```

But if I use a filter, it returns no documents:

```
"query": {
        "bool":{
            "must":[
                 {"simple_query_string": { "query":"great guide" }} 
            ],
            "filter":{
              "terms":{
                "groups":["Local Business"]
              }
            }
        }
    },
```

If I remove the "filter" key and values, then the document is retrieved.

Why isn't the filter matching the document ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `groups` field is of type [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html), then the query you've mentioned works as expected.

However it wouldn't work if the field `groups` if of type [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html). In that case the below query would actually fit what you are looking for.

### Query for group - Type text

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "simple_query_string":{  
                  "query":"great guide"
               }
            }
         ],
         "filter":{  
            "match":{  
               "groups":"Local Business"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The reason the query you've mentioned doesn't work for the field of type `text` is because this field goes through [Analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) phase making use of [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) by default where it would first convert `Local Business` into small cases and then saves `local` and `business` as two individual words in the inverted index.

Elasticsearch would only give you results if the words you query match what's available in the index.

And what `keyword` does is, it saves `Local Business` as is in inverted index.

**Note:** You can try the query you have by replacing `groups` with `groups.keyword` if mapping hasn't been defined and is created dynamically.

Hope this helps!